# Why is it still outputting the form when the session is registered?

Tags: php, mysql, html

Okay so I have a script to check to see if someone has logged in. But the login it still displays the form to login. Here is the current script:

```
<?php
if(session_is_registered(myusername)){
echo $_SESSION['myusername'];
echo "<br /><a class='linkText' href='logout.php'>Logout!</a></div>";
}
else{
$login_form=<<<'LOGIN'
                    Login<br /><br /><div class="heading_02">
                    <form name="form2" method="post" action="checklogin.php" style="display:inline">
                            <input type="text" name="myusername" id="myusername" class="user" /><br />
                            <input type="password" name="mypassword" id="mypassword" class="pass" /><br />
                            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" class="green_login_02" />
                    </form>
                <a style="color: #A2FF00; text-decoration: none;" href="signup.php">Sign-up</a>

                </div>
LOGIN;
echo $login_form;
}
?>
```

Just as an extra side note this part of like a clamp figuratively speaking so this is inside the first half of a clamp. The clamp syntax goes like this:

```
<? include("clamp1.php"); ?>
content
<? include("clamp2.php"); ?>
```

This appears in the first half of the clamp if that is any help.

Comment: Does it work after refreshing the page?

Comment: Not enough code is posted. What's in checklogin? What's in session_is_registered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['myusername']='Ka';


function logged_in($session_name){
    if (isset($session_name) and !(empty($session_name))){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}


if(logged_in($_SESSION['myusername'])){
echo $_SESSION['myusername'];
echo "<br /><a class='linkText' href='logout.php'>Logout!</a></div>";
}
else{
$login_form=<<<'LOGIN'
                    Login<br /><br /><div class="heading_02">
                    <form name="form2" method="post" action="checklogin.php" style="display:inline">
                            <input type="text" name="myusername" id="myusername" class="user" /><br />
                            <input type="password" name="mypassword" id="mypassword" class="pass" /><br />
                            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" class="green_login_02" />
                    </form>
                <a style="color: #A2FF00; text-decoration: none;" href="signup.php">Sign-up</a>

                </div>
LOGIN;
echo $login_form;
}
```

Works, the function session_is_registered is DEPRECATED (http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-is-registered.php). try making methods to check if a session variable is set. Don`t forget session_start()